# Using API in GoogleSheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to import in google sheet data from https://www.coinspeaker.com/ieo/feed/

```
function callCoinSpeaker() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.coinspeaker.com/ieo/feed/");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  var fact = response.getContentText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([fact]);
}
```

The script works fine, but I don't know how to format the output that is all in a single cell (A1).

I would like to create a code that automatically format the output splitting into column and row. Any example of formatting output from API request?Thanks ALL!

Comment: Hello @Pierandrea, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please describe what formatting do you want to apply to this data (how to split it, etc) so we can provide more detailed answers? Also, just as a suggestion, you can check out the following links which may be relevant to what you are trying to do: [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) and [GAS Regular Expressions](https://scriptingwithshiva.blogspot.com/2018/04/google-apps-script-regular-expressions.html). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Instead using script, I have used =IMPORTXML("https://www.coinspeaker.com/ieo/feed/"; "/*") .
Now I can work to create a Macro to split the text into column and row!Thanks!

Comment: That's definitely another possibility ;) good job. Don't hesitate to ask if you have any other questions. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What I think about your issue in when you're making a GET request to your link, the response is back as a string.
To be able to use the data, you should parse your response with the method `JSON.parse(fact)`
Use `Logger.Log(JSON.parse(fact))` to see what is happening.